# Trouble linking my source code to git repository

Tags: git

I'm using Git 1.7.4.1 on Mac 10.6.6.  I want to commit my existing project to a repository that was just created.  However, when I'm in the directory where my project is located, I get this error ...

```
git clone http://dalvarado@mydomain.com/socialmediaproxy.git
fatal: destination path 'socialmediaproxy' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

This is true, but the directory "socialmediaproxy" is what I want to put in my repository.  How do I do this?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: What is your "existing project"? Is it a copy of that publicly hosted project, based on a tarball or something? Or is it a directory containing only a couple things you want to add to it?

Answer (score 1):

You say that the remote repository was newly created, so I assume that it has no commits in it yet.  I'm also assuming that your existing directory is not under the control of git yet.  If those assumptions are true, you could take the following steps:

1. `cd socialmediaproxy`
2. `git init` to initialize this directory as a git repository with a working tree.  That will create a `.git` directory in `socialmediaproxy` which will store all the history of your repository.
3. `git add .` to stage all the files in that directory for the first version of the project in that repository.  If there are generated files in that directory, you should be more careful, just adding the files that you want in the repository, and ignoring the others by creating a `.gitignore` file.
4. `git commit -m "First version of the socialmediaproxy project"` to create the first commit in your repository.
5. `git remote add origin http://dalvarado@mydomain.com/socialmediaproxy.git` to set up a "remote" called `origin` to point to the remote repository.  ("Remotes" are essentially just convenient nicknames for other repositories.)
6. `git push -u origin master` to push your only commit on the `master` branch to the remote repository.  The `-u` option says to associate the branch `master` in the `origin` repository as the "upstream" repository of your `master` branch.  This enables various helpful defaults in `git` and produces more helpful output from `git status` and other commands.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations.  Your assumptions were correct and we even deleted and recreated the repository, but I got these errors on running the last command ... error: failed to push some refs to 'http://dalvarado@mydomain.com/test.git

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` is for creating a new repository from an existing one.

You want to fetch from socialmediaproxy:

```
git remote add origin http://dalvarado@mydomain.com/socialmediaproxy.git
git fetch origin
git checkout master
```

Either that, or you could just remove the new repository you just created and re-create it as a clone (like you tried to do).  There is no reason to create an empty repository if you want it to be a clone of another repository.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the socialmediaproxy directory you have, as the clone will create it for you.